# Ordering of Pages in Printed LEGO Catalogues

Tags: history, marketing

While looking at some of the scanned LEGO catalogues on [BrickSet](https://brickset.com/library/catalogues), I have noticed that the UK catalogues (at least the ones I looked into) seem to be ordered "backwards" compared to what I'm used to from Germany: They start with LEGO System (or even Technic) pages, while Duplo is appended at the end (e.g. look at the [1997](https://images.brickset.com/library/view/?f=catalogues/c97uk) one).

In German catalogues, in contrast, pages are invariably ordered roughly by age ranges, i.e. the catalogues start with Duplo, followed by Basic (or whatever it was called in the respective time), followed by "System" (town, knights, space, ...; possibly starting with juniorized town in the years that was a thing), followed by Technic.

Is there a specific reason for that? (e.g. is that the usual way to order toy catalogues in the UK vs. Germany, was it just started differently and then LEGO stuck with its respective tradition in the respective countries, etc.?)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just basically something they did on purpose. I would suggest that you check more like this to confirm your suspicions, but as far as I am concerned, different countries maybe have different styles of doing things related to counting.

Comment: Hi LegoCrusader and thank you for this contribution! I took the liberty to edit your answer a bit, as your age is in no way relevant to the correctness of your ideas or answer. On the other hand, could you please elaborate a bit on what you mean by "doing things related to counting"?